# How to get to the bottom of random crashes

Tags: ios

I am working with my app in test flight now and I have experienced this maybe only one time myself. How can I get to the bottom of a rare crash without it being hooked up to the computer? The only information is that it occasionally will freeze, but other than that it doesn't seem to be happening with a specific action. How do I debug this?

Comment: Sounds like an operational issue to me and to continue investigating we'd need more information.

Comment: That's the problem that I have. Is there a library out there that I can use that can get her information about a crash? I cannot seem to duplicate the crash on the sim or with it hooked up to my Mac

Comment: If the app crashes then Apple will have the crash log.  You can only really work with a crash log.

Comment: I'm sure testflight provides a crash report and stack trace. What does that say?

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I didn't know that was on there! Gimme a second to post it

Comment: hmm yeah its an odd thing because test flight says that i have 0 crashes, but it definitely has... Thoughts? Could it be that my app is just having a memory problem and isnt crashing but hanging up and users are just getting impatient?

Comment: Maybe you have a piece of code that it can't get out of so it looks like a crash but isn't the code is still running. i.e. infinite loop.

Comment: An easy method to improve things is turn all reasonable warnings on and fix whatever they report (that usually removes lots of bugs), and to use the static analyser and fix what it reports (that usually removes a few very well hidden bugs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some approaches:

- Write log files to the disk, which you can later sync. or send to a server for investigating which operations succeeded before it crashed
- Integrate a custom (such as [KSCrash](https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash), [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com), etc.) crash reporter tool that allows you to see a backtrace (Note though that enabling Bitcode will make things *much* harder)
- Try to reproduce the problem in the simulator (try different builds, debug build, release build, send memory warnings, etc.)
- Try to reproduce with a computer connected. Interactive debugging makes things so much easier.

Good luck!